# Allowing error messages to bubble up

Tags: c, error-handling

gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
    c89

I have always wondered what is the best practice when returning error messages from called functions?

In one of my shared libraries I am creating I have this function:

```
/* Create directory structure */
apr_status_t dir_create(apr_pool_t *mem_pool)
{
#define SRC "test_src"

    apr_fileperms_t file_perms =
        APR_FPROT_UWRITE   |
        APR_FPROT_GWRITE   |
        APR_FPROT_WWRITE   |
        APR_FPROT_UREAD    |
        APR_FPROT_GREAD    |
        APR_FPROT_WREAD    |
        APR_FPROT_UEXECUTE |
        APR_FPROT_GEXECUTE;

    if(apr_dir_make(SRC, file_perms, mem_pool) != APR_SUCCESS) {
        LOG_CRIT("Failed to create directory");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The `LOG_CRIT` will display the appropriate error message related to the errno.

In my application that will call this function I have this:

```
if(dir_create(mem_pool) != TRUE) {
    return 1;
}
LOG_INFO("Directory has been created");
```

For a example when the above fails it will log like this:

```
[CRITICAL] dir_create:28: error [File exists] Failed to create directory
```

I am wondering should I place the error message in the application that calls the library function. Or should you always display the error message as soon as you get it at the earliest time?

In the case above I display the error message in the called function. And when the function returns I just return 1 to end the application or do something else.

Another thought, it is better to return the error indicator, and let the calling function display the source of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options, getting increasingly crazy - you probably have an instinct for what will suit your situation ;-P  This is more to stimulate your awareness of options:

- capture as much as you think sensible - `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `errno`, error description, operation being attempted, parameters, outcome  etc. - on the line detecting the error
- principle: **do only what the caller wants you to do**; lots of approaches with different compromises:

  - return a small, easily testable data value (number or pointer), but provide some access functions to get the other information captured above easily so the code you "return into" can do whatever they like...

    - e.g. caller may dereference that pointer to get error detail, `strerror()`-like functions, caller given a pointer to printable error message (if visibility into the meaning of that message isn't needed by the caller)...
  - immediately notify a caller-controlled routine, which can suppress or redirect the error as the caller deems appropriate; e.g. your library could provide a pointer to a function that you call, which the caller could redirect - the default could log to standard error or some other generally acceptible action
  - design your library code to be `#include`d and use a caller-provided preprocessor macro stipulating error handling behaviour
  - hardcode output of an error message from your library, but let the caller modify the stream to which that may be sent so they can suppress it if desired

You need to get more serious about this kind of thing if applications using your library are likely to want to try operations speculatively (e.g. failover or transactional semantics), especially if certain error actions have irreversible consequences (e.g. some batch job systems consider the job to have failed if anything is printed on stderr - but from the perspective of the program your library function may not constitute failure, or popping up an graphical error dialog box would frustrate unattended operation).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend logging the error message at the lowest level possible, as you're doing here.  That's especially important if you need to access `errno`, which otherwise might have changed by the time you get to a higher level function.  At this level, I'd make the error messages as technical and specific as possible.

Based on the return value of your library functions, your application code might take some action (for example, it could display a popup window giving a human-readable description of the error, or it could write to `stderr`).  This would normally be done at the highest level possible - the UI level, if you like.